# how to print json from bash in single line

Tags: bash, jq

I have to derive a json String from a text file but the output happens to go into multiple lines.
My code

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="$1"
dest_file= output/output.jsonl
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
    model_name="test-model"
    JSON_STRING=$(  jq -n  --arg model "$model_name" --arg prompt "$name" '{model: $model, prompt: $prompt}' )
    printf "%s" "$JSON_STRING" >> "$dest_file"
done < "$filename"
```

The file is a simple test.txt
with only 1 line

```
 primer query
```

and the output I get is this

```
{
  "model": "test-model",
  "prompt": "primer query"
}
```

What I want is `{"model": "test-model", "prompt": "primer query"}` in one line
I tried `jq -c` but then it gives empty output

Comment: You need to combine the `-c` flag with your existing command: `jq -cn --arg model "$model_name" --arg prompt "$name" '{$model, $prompt}'`

Comment: Or even `jq -cn --arg model "$model_name" --arg prompt "$name" '$ARGS.named'`

Comment: Show us _how_ you tried `jq -c` that resulted in empty output in enough detail that we can see the problem ourselves.

Comment: I just replaced jq -n with jq -c in the above code

Comment: @vkaul11 You need *both* the `-n` and `-c` options (or combine them as `-cn` or `-nc`); the blank output you got was due to removing the `-n`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks complicated and definitely doesn't require `bash`, the simple `sh` should suffice here.

Why store the output of the command in a variable and then print and format + redirect the content of the variable?

```
jq -nc \
  --arg model "$model_name" \
  --arg prompt "$name" \
  '{$model, $prompt}' \
  >> "$dest_file"
```

The option [`-c`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Invokingjq) produces *compact output* which means that everything will be in a single line.